# Searching and sorting by related model in CGridView Yii

Tags: php, database, yii

I want to make my CGridView columns searchable after reading [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview) the problem is when i use one `cdbCriteria->with` condition it works fine. But It gives an error when i add more than one `cdbCriteria->with` condition. More specifically I am pasting my code here.

```
           $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
           $criteria->with = array( 'teacherGradeSection','course'  );
           $criteria->with = array( 'teacherGradeSection','teacher' );
           $criteria->together = true;
           $criteria->compare('course.name', $this->course_search, true );
           $criteria->compare('teacher.firstname', $this->teacher_search, true );
```

When i use only one with condition it works fine but gives an error when more than one with condition is used.

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
```

Edit 1:
These are the available relations

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'submissions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Submission', 'task_id'),
        'teacherGradeSection' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TeacherGradeSection', 'teacher_grade_section_id'),
        'course'    => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Course', array('course_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'teacherGradeSection'),
         'teacher'=>  array(self::HAS_MANY,'Teacher',array('teacher_teacher_id'=>'teacher_id'),'through'=>'teacherGradeSection'),
   ); }
```

As suugested by @Nisic and @Noam148 when i use 
 `$criteria->with=array('teacherGradeSection','course','teacher ')`
I got the following error

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'teacherGradeSection'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `task` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `teacher_grade_section` `teacherGradeSection` ON (`t`.`teacher_grade_section_id`=`teacherGradeSection`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `course` `course` ON (`course`.`id`=`teacherGradeSection`.`course_id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `teacher_grade_section` `teacherGradeSection` ON (`t`.`teacher_grade_section_id`=`teacherGradeSection`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `teacher` `teacher` ON (`teacher`.`teacher_id`=`teacherGradeSection`.`teacher_teacher_id`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try defining two relations that will resolve the conflict

```
'teacherGradeSection' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TeacherGradeSection', 'teacher_grade_section_id'),
'teacherGradeSectiontwo' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TeacherGradeSection', 'teacher_grade_section_id'),
```

and in your criteria

```
$criteria->with['course'] = array( 'teacherGradeSection','course'  );
$criteria->with['teacher']= array( 'teacherGradeSectiontwo','teacher' );
```

Comment: +1 Its working. but i doubt whether its a good idea or not. I am waiting for others to answer. i will accept your answer if others gives the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `with` will actually replace your first `with` so you will not eager load the course, so when you later reference it in `compare` you get the error.

You need only one with that prepares both, course and teacher. I can't be sure how to write it without the database schema, but you can blind try this:

```
$criteria->with = array( 'teacherGradeSection','course', 'teacher'  );
```

or just explain us the relations

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$criteria->with` property one time. When you used `$criteria->with` for the second time you **override** the first one.

See here how to use the with property. On this way you add 3 different relations to your 'CDbCriteria':

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array( 'teacherGradeSection','course','teacher');
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->compare('course.name', $this->course_search, true );
$criteria->compare('teacher.firstname', $this->teacher_search, true );
```